# Photo_upload permission depracated in facebook, how to fix this PHP script to working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, photo-upload

I have a php script below, to upload photo to facebook cover

```
<?php
if(is_single()){
if($_REQUEST['state']){
$imgsource = show_src('851','315');
}else{
$imgsource = $_POST['o'];
}
if($imgsource){
require_once "script/facebook.php";
$config = array(
'appId' => get_theme_option('app_id'),
'secret' => get_theme_option('secret'),
'fileUpload' => true,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$photo = str_replace(home_url( '/' ),'',$imgsource);
$message = get_theme_option('descover');
if($user_id) {
try {
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
'source' => '@' . $photo,
'message' => $message,
)
);
$hasil3 = '<div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-header">
<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
<h2>You\'re almost done!</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_directory").'/images/eee.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=%27.%24user_id.%27%3Fpreview_cover%3D' . $ret_obj['id'] . '" class="btn primary" target="_blank">Go to Facebook Profile</a>
</div>
</div>
<button data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn large success btnsingle">Preview Timeline</button>';
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
'scope' => 'photo_upload'
));
error_log($e->getType());
error_log($e->getMessage());
}
} else {
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
if($imgsource){header('Location: '.$login_url);}
}
}
}
?>
```

its not working now, because photo_upload permission in API depracated, how to fix this PHP script to working?

i already tried change photo_upload with these, but looks like still not right:

```
publish_stream
publish_actions
user_photos
```

Comment: `publish_actions` _is_ the correct permission. (`user_photos` is for reading, and `publish_stream` is also long gone.)

Comment: Log your access token, and [debug it here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), to verify if it actually contains that permission.

Comment: @CBroe here is the result, how is it? : Missing Required Property The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.

Comment: So i just change 2 photo_upload in the code, with publish_actions? already tried it & get this message, what should i do?: Submit for Login Review
Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook. Submit for review now or learn more.

Comment: When testing this with an account that has a role in the app (admin/developer/tester), you can ignore that message. But you will have to submit your app for review, before you can ask normal users for this permission.

Comment: but after get above message, the photo in the script still not uploaded to my facebook cover, my role is admin/developer in the app. is it already right just change 2 photo_upload in the code, with publish_actions? do i need Submit the app for Approval first? thank you before & gbu for helping me, really appreciated it

Comment: Did you continue with the login dialog after that message, and actually grant the permission? Have you debugged your access token by now?

Comment: Yes i continue with the login dialog, clicked Yes to grant the permission, but still no photo uploaded to facebook cover or to my profile photos. Here is current debug, is this already work to upload facebook cover/photo? http://freakimage.com/images/540debug.jpg

Comment: That has nothing to do with uploading a photo – that’s only relevant when you share that URL on Facebook, and want facebook to extract the “correct” meta data you want to be used for that.

Comment: Your code uses the old PHP SDK v3 – the current version is v5. Instead of trying to debug and fix this old script, I would recommend to rewrite from scratch – the documentation has easy examples for handling login/asking for permissions and uploading photos, so that should not be too big of a problem. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

Comment: thank you for the link, i am trying it, how i can thanked you? you are the best!